# android - choose intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

This show the box with the applications to choose an image or take a picture with camera. If I select Camera this let me to take a picture but there is no return or save option. I updated my answer posting the activity result code.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 1:
                if (data != null)
                {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Only called when a image from gallery is selected");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Data is null");
                }
                break;

        }
    }
   private void ChooseImage()
{

    // Create gallery intent
    Intent _intentGallery = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    _intentGallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    _intentGallery.putExtra("return-data", true);

   // startActivityForResult(_intentGallery, 1);


    // Create camera intent
    Intent galleryIntent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    // Create chooser
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.choose_an_application));

    // Create list of gallery intents
    List<Intent> galleryIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();

    // Add intents to list
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    for (ResolveInfo ri: pm.queryIntentActivities(_intentGallery, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY))
    {
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        galleryIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Show dialog
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, galleryIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
    startActivityForResult(chooser, 1);
}
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `onActivityResult`. Then you can get data.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

In this case, `REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is 1 as you defined it, so change it to 1.
Don't forget the manifest rule `uses-feature`.

See more: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html